# Проблема при установке lubuntu: update-initramfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

Всем привет. Совсем новичек в линукс, надеялся на легкую установку на свой второй старый ноутбук. Пробовал установить lubuntu, в режиме работы с флешки все замечательно, но при установке каждый раз получаю ошибку:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-21-generic

cp: preserving times for /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_jHPPnS/usr/lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/kernel/fs/cifs.ko: read-only file system

cant create regular file /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_jHPPnS/usr/lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/kernel/crypto/md4.ko
```

И так далее, много строчек. Пробовал проводить какие-то манипцляции с initramfs-tools, но это ничего не дало. Совершенно не понимаю, что не так в моей ситуации

Comment: Проверьте, не умирает ли жёсткий диск

Comment: Ох, звучит грустно. Спасибо, проверю

Comment: @andreymal Вы были правы. У меня под рукой был лишний ssd, который, кстати, без линукса не особо заводился на этом ноутбуке, на который все без проблем быстро установилось. Так что решил сразу две проблемы. Спасибо!